# Flutter socket.io connected but throws error(server node.js)

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

```
// please try to help if you can
socketConnect(){
IO.Socket  socket =  IO.io('https://8476-113-20-17-134.ngrok.io/',
    IO.OptionBuilder()
        .disableAutoConnect()
        .setTransports(['websocket'])
        .build()
);
socket.connect();
socket.onConnect((_) {
  print('connect');
});
socket.on("testingnirav", (data) => print(data) );
}
```

**Show Connected in Backend Server Log but throws below error in flutter socket_io_client**

**E/flutter ( 9164): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
E/flutter ( 9164): #0      Socket.onHandshake (package:socket_io_client/src/engine/socket.dart:481:5)
E/flutter ( 9164): #1      Socket.onPacket (package:socket_io_client/src/engine/socket.dart:449:11)**

```
// link send me to this location 
pingInterval = data['pingInterval'];
```

Comment: Just minor change in this socket.on("testingnirav", (data) => print(data.toString()) );
as toString for data

Comment: still not working

Comment: try to initiliaze this way : socket = io(SocketUtils.CONNECTION_URL, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });  and try this first its connecting or not ?